# What is the order of evaluation of the sentences of a script in bash?

Tags: shell-script

from left to right? or vice versa?

example:

```
If [! -z "$ foo"] && [$ foo2 -eq 0]; then
    echo "something"
fi
```

What is the evaluation done first?

```
[! -z "$ foo"]
```

or

```
[$ foo2 -eq 0]
```

thanks!

Comment: Do consider testing your shell code in something like https://www.shellcheck.net/  The code that you have posted has multiple typos.

Answer (score 8):

In a shell script saying

```
if [ ! -z "$foo" ] && [ "$foo2" -eq 0 ]; then
    echo 'something'
fi
```

the first test, `[ ! -z "$foo" ]` (better written as `[ -n "$foo" ]`), will run first.  The second test will *only* run if the first test succeeded.  If *both* tests succeed, meaning `$foo` is a value that is not empty and `$foo2` has an arithmetic value equal to zero, then the `echo` will be executed.

The `&&` operator works like similar operators in other languages.  The shell implements [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) and will only evaluate the right hand side of `&&` if the left hand side is *true*.

This particular `if` statement could also be written without using the `if` keyword, as

```
[ ! -z "$foo" ] && [ "$foo2" -eq 0 ] && echo 'something'
```

Although using `if ...; then ...; fi` is IMHO clearer.

Again, the `echo` would only execute if *both* preceding tests succeeded.

Comment: Possibly helpful- the way I parse `&&` and `||` in my head are "and if so, then" and "and if not, then" respectively.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The `echo` inside the if is by way of example. In the original script there are other commands.

Answer (score 3):

**tl;dr**

As stated in [the answer you already have](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/511544/315749), according to the definition of *AND lists* in the shell command language, `[ ! -z "$foo" ]` is executed first and then, only if it returns an exit status of zero, `[ "$foo2" -eq 0 ]` is executed.

---

The execution order of commands in Bash is specified in the "Shell Commands" section of the [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Commands). In what follows I am assuming the definitions provided there, possibly verbatim reproduced (even if not formatted as quotations, for convenience).

For Bash and the other POSIX compliant shells, more formal (but likely less friendly) definitions can be found in the "Shell Command Language" chapter (particularly, in paragraphs "Shell Commands" and "Shell Grammar") of [The Open Group Base Specifications](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/shell.html).

In the code

```bash
if [ ! -z "$foo" ] && [ "$foo2" -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "something"
fi
```

we have an `if` *compound command*, an *AND list* and three *simple commands*.

The general syntax of the `if` conditional construct is

```bash
if test-commands; then
    consequent-commands;
[elif more-test-commands; then
    more-consequents;]
[else alternate-consequents;]
fi
```

If the exit status of `test-commands` is zero, the `consequent-commands` clause is executed.

Our `test-commands` clause is an AND list, which is a sequence of *pipelines* separated by `&&`, as in

```bash
command1 && command2
```

where `command2` is executed if, and only if, the exit status of `command1` is zero.

AND lists are executed with left associativity. Thus:

```bash
command1 && command2 && command3
```

is executed as if it were written as (using parentheses as pseudocode grouping operators and temporarily forgetting their meaning in Bash language):

```bash
(((command1) && command2) && command3)
```

In our AND list

```bash
[ ! -z "$foo" ] && [ "$foo2" -eq 0 ]
```

the first pipeline

```bash
[ ! -z "$foo" ]
```

is executed first. Only if it succeeds the second pipeline

```bash
[ "$foo2" -eq 0 ]
```

is executed. The exit status of the last executed command in the list is the one considered by `if`.

A pipeline is a sequence of one or more commands separated by one of the control operators `|` or `|&`. Both of our two pipelines are just simple commands.

A simple command is a sequence of words separated by `blanks`, terminated by one of the shell’s control operators. Simple commands do not pose execution order issues.

For the records, the simple commands in our AND list are composed by the (builtin) command `[` and four arguments to it, respectively `!`, `-z`, `"$foo"`, `]` and `"$foo2"`, `-eq`, `0`, `]`.

Finally, the `consequent-commands` clause of our `if` compound command is the simple command `echo "something"`—which, again, does not pose any execution order issue.

Comment: Nice! With answers that long, I am in favor of putting a `tl;dr` section on top.

Comment: @Bananguin Thanks, I definitely agree. Answer edited.

Comment: very nice! thanks for the manual!